# SQL How to make principle db mirror and mirror db principle

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-mirroring

I need to temporarily set up Idera SQL Compliance manager for the mirror database. but, the mirror database is not showing the required database since its being mirrored. So I am guessing I need to somehow flip the principle to mirror and mirror to principle so that I can setup Idera SQL Compliance manager. Any advice is super helpful

Comment: You can call Idera. They can walk you through their product and could also help you with the setup.

Comment: tried for the past week no answer or chat available